# Basketball sits on the back of the rim motionless after an attempted shot. What is the ruling?

Tags: rules, basketball

Saw this in one of the NBA play off highlights but no one said how it was ruled. A shot attempt bounces on the rim and settles to a dead stop on the rim's bracket never entering the basket itself. Is it a dead ball like when the ball sticks between backboard and rim? Or what?

Comment: I believe there may be an answer hidden in this question: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/what-happens-if-a-basketball-stops-on-the-rim-as-time-expires. However, your question appears to be more general and therefore, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [NBA Rule Book](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_6.html):

> Rule 6, Section 5
>
> (a) The ball shall be put into play in the center circle by a jump ball between any two opponents:
>
> > (6) The ball comes to rest on the basket flange or becomes lodged between the basket ring and the backboard
>
> (b) In all cases above, the jump ball shall be between any two opponents in the game at that time. If injury, ejection or disqualification makes it necessary for any player to be replaced, his substitute may not participate
> in the jump ball.

So in this situation, if the ball comes to rest on the flange it shall be ruled a jump ball.